# Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, out-of-memory, mcafee

I have written a form based application in `vb.net` using Visual Studio 2017 - within Visual Studio it runs successfully.

However, after publication and upon running the app, I receive the error message:

> **Following failure messages were detected:**
>           + Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800705AA)

I have done some research into this and have found that disabling McAfee prevents this error from occurring (this makes sense as a McAfee warning occasionally pops up when trying to open the program).  However, as I am writing this for a corporation, disabling McAfee is not an option.

Ideally I'd like way I can get around this error.  Failing that, is there something I can disable within McAfee?

Comment: It is a consumer-level product, not something that is appropriate in an enterprise where LOB apps are common.  The only decent way to get the authorities to decide to switch to a better solution is to make it their problem.

Comment: Are there setting that the authorities can change?

Comment: What kind of things does the program do?

Comment: @HansPassant There are McAfee products for business - I would hope they are using one of those rather than the consumer version.

Comment: @JHerk Is the program signed with a digital certificate as suggested in [How to troubleshoot when Endpoint Security blocks third-party applications](https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB88482)?

Comment: It is signed with a digital certificate.  However, it is a test certificate made by visual studio.

Comment: As for what the program does; it runs queries on our databases and performs some basic screen scraping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were able to solve this by getting our iso to add the relevant folders to the McAfee trusted list and include the executable in the global exclusions list.  The system treated the newly published app as malicious and this needed to be changed manually.